# How to pass parameter to Scala object

Tags: scala, akka, akka-actor

I want to create actor only once and use its reference in the app again and again. For that I created a Scala object and everything is working fine, but when I try to use child actor I am getting `NullPointerException`. 
Here is the code:

```
object ActorManager {
  val getTestActorRef: ActorRef = system.actorOf(Props[TestActor], name = "testActor")
}
```

The problem occurs when I want to instantiate a child actor. Here is code:

```
object ActorManager {
  var context: ActorContext=_

  val getTestActorRef: ActorRef = system.actorOf(Props[TestActor], name = "testActor")

  val getTestChildActorRef: ActorRef = context.actorOf(Props[TestActor], name = "testActor")
}

class ParentTestActor extends Actor {

  ActorManager.context=context

  val childActor = ActorManager.getTestChildActorRef

  def receive ={
    //some code here
  }    
}
```

When `ParentTestActor` is instantiated it throws

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: null
```

Please help how can I resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

You should not share any actor related state outside actor. Specifically you should not share akka-specific variables like context, self, etc.

Child actors should be created `only` from inside parent! It could be reasonable to initialize them from parent `preStart` (read about actors lifecycle)

If you need so much direct actor ref available in static constant, add `child: AtomicReference[ActorRef]` in your object and set it from parent actor.